# getting error at 'ExecuteNonQuery'

Tags: vb.net, executenonquery

The error is `'Sqlexception was unhanded ' There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = * ]`

```
Dim con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source = C:\Users\vineet\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sqlProject\sqlProject\studentDB.sdf")
Dim dcmd As SqlCeCommand
Dim da As SqlCeDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '   ShowData()
End Sub

Public Sub ShowData()
    dcmd = New SqlCeCommand("Select * FROM studentTable", con)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    'now we will populate the dataset with the help of data adapter
    da = New SqlCeDataAdapter(dcmd)
    ds = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
    DataGridStudents.DataSource = ds.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ShowData()
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    dcmd = New SqlCeCommand("Delete * From studentTable Where name=@name", con)
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox6.Text)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    dcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ShowData()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    dcmd = New SqlCeCommand("Insert Into studentTable(ID,name,address,mobile,email) Values(@fID,@fname,@faddress,@fmobile,@femail)")
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", TextBox1.Text)
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faddress", TextBox1.Text)
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmobile", TextBox1.Text)
    dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@femail", TextBox1.Text)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    dcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ShowData()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Would you like to share the error with us? Or should we guess?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `TextBox1.Text` for every parameter value.

```
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", TextBox1.Text)
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faddress", TextBox1.Text)
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmobile", TextBox1.Text)
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@femail", TextBox1.Text)
```

I am not sure from the code posted, what the names of the actual UI controls that need to map to each of the pieces of data are, but I am pretty sure `TextBox1.Text` is not all of those in one.

Comment: you are right , TextBox1.Text is temporary ,but  It should have worked

Comment: wo w it there was mistake in hte query

Answer (score 1):

It should be ..

```
dcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fID", TextBox1.Text)
```

and it should be ..

```
dcmd = New SqlCeCommand("Insert Into studentTable(ID,name,address,mobile,email) Values(@fID,@fname,@faddress,@fmobile,@femail)", con)
```